# Multinomial logisitc regression in WEKA

Tags: weka, logistic-regression

I am working on multinomial logistic regression using WEKA tool. For experimental purpose, I was working on weather example and trying to predict outlook feature using logistic regression. Plz help to interpret the result. Especially the use of coefficient and how to construct prediction equation from that. Outlook feature can hold three value (Sunny, Overcast,Rainy).

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -R 1.0E-8 -M -1
Relation:     weather.symbolic
Instances:    14
Attributes:   5
              outlook
              temperature
              humidity
              windy
              play
Test mode:    10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Logistic Regression with ridge parameter of 1.0E-8
Coefficients...
                                    Class
Variable                            sunny               overcast
================================================================
temperature=hot                   14.3585                45.2229
temperature=mild                  -6.0885               -34.2035
temperature=cool                  -7.0523                -4.1787
humidity                           1.1354               -31.1848
windy                              0.6535               -29.4463
play                               0.4818               -90.7874
Intercept                          4.6263                50.8973


Odds Ratios...
                                    Class
Variable                            sunny               overcast
================================================================
temperature=hot              1721195.3778  4.3658888975323775E19
temperature=mild                   0.0023                      0
temperature=cool                   0.0009                 0.0153
humidity                           3.1125                      0
windy                              1.9223                      0
play                               1.6191                      0
```